# Adding Matrix from frontend form

Tags: matrix

I am using a similar approach with the code provided [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/how-to-get-matrix-editor-into-frontend).

I am able to get an initial block to save, but when I go back to the form and try to add another a new block is not created. My application is basically to add notes to an entry. The notes contain an editorName, reviewNotes and a datetime stamp.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[editorialHistory][new43][type]" value="block">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[editorialHistory][new43][fields][editorName]" value="{{currentUser.getFriendlyName()}}">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[editorialHistory][new43][fields][reviewDate]" value="{{"now"|date("F j, Y, g:i a")}}">
```

Comment: Is the handle of your block type actually named "block"?  One thing that I found to block the update/creation of blocks was a missing/invalid block type. If that doesn't help, could you perhaps put the whole entry form in a pastebin somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the block type is actually "block". Unfortunate and I will probably change that.

Comment: Could you update your question with the whole form code?

Comment: Unfortunately I abandoned this idea in favor of s simpler implementation that does not require matrix fields. I wish I still had the html form code but do not.